# Trac. Uploading attachment shows its contents in History View for all users. How to customize privileges?

Tags: security, trac

I'm using ["MyPage"](http://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracMyPagePlugin&rct=j&q=mypage%20plugin%20trac&ei=DriNTuGnEdCRswaSlogb&usg=AFQjCNEw9S1T8vsbM3_b-YoZd4O5VcOSxQ) plugin for Trac.

I have figured out it is useful to store SSH keys on my private page as an attachment, so I can clone my GIT repository from any computer.
Then I have our found that any user who can view a History tab, can see the content of the attachment :/

Any idea how to secure this thing?

Comment: With 'history tab' you mean '/timeline'?

Answer (score 0):

Since in general this is meant as a feature, you'd like to just block one or several specific attachments from common view.

If this is true, [TracFineGrainedPermissions](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions) is for you. Then you'll be able to have something like

```
[wiki:Users/KilldaclickHome@*/attachment/supersecret.file]
killdaclick = ATTACHMENT_VIEW
* = !ATTACHMENT_VIEW
```

to just deny access to the specific file to anyone but yourself. Have a look at the [FineGrainedPageAuthzEditorPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/FineGrainedPageAuthzEditorPlugin) for a alternative way to define these permission (from the web-UI instead of direct access to the authz file).

You'll certainly think twice about granting permission 'TRAC_ADMIN' - just a hint that these user can edit the file and possibly circumvent any restriction. But 'TRAC_ADMIN' will have 'ATTACHMENT_VIEW' anyway.